# How do you finish a window installation?

Tags: windows, finishing, trim, sill

After the window has been secured in the rough opening, how do you finish the inside part of the installation? For example adding a window sill and trimming out the inner portion of the rough opening, not the finishing trim around the window. Also does anyone have any videos or pictures of the process? The type and maker of the particular window i am installing is a ThermaStar by Pella 28" x 36" 10 Series Vinyl Double Pane Single Hung Window. Thank you

Comment: What kind and make of windows do you have?  Different styles are finished differently.

Comment: ThermaStar by Pella 28" x 36" 10 Series Vinyl Double Pane Single Hung Window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

google "trim interior window" =

video:
http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/video/0,,20046338,00.html

steps:
http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/intro/0,,218130,00.html

Assuming you have already:
1) insulated in the rough opening with low-expansion spray foam
2) sheetrocked to the rough opening

Comment: thank you i was talking about something else and probably didn't word it right but in the video i saw what i need to do. thank you again. :)